# "Choosing appropriate architectures" - singular or plural agreement?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, agreement

Choosing appropriate architectures **{are}** crucial

or

Choosing appropriate architectures **{is}** crucial

To my knowledge [choosing something] is a single action, it should be followed by [is].  Please correct me if it is wrong and will be great if you come up with a little explanation...!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think - first one is correct - "Choosing appropriate architectures {are} crucial" because u have specified architectures i.e. plural. So i think 1st one is correct.

Comment: It is singular. Here the subject is 'choosing'. Choosing what? It could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject of your sentence is **choosing appropriate architectures**, which has singular agreement. The  subject is **choosing**, not **architectures**.

The sentence should read:

> Choosing appropriate architectures is crucial.

Comment: 'Architecture' could be used as a count noun (such as different styles), but it doesn't matter -- the subject is 'choosing' which is singular.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my context is software engineering where more than one software architectures can be used as various types of computer systems with interact with one another.

Comment: @ prasanth.Even  if  it is  architectures   the  subject  is  choosing  so  is  crucial is  correct.

Comment: +1 I’ve edited for clarity. Feel free to roll back the changes or to edit further.

Comment: @ Lawerence.The OP is  not  able  to  understand.So  I have  given  many  examples. Thank   you  for  the  edit.

Comment: @Prasanth: You can change the voice, like: Architectures to be chosen are....in case you are particular about the plural nature of architecture.